# How to loop json attribute in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, loops

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION parse_json (arg_t text) 
RETURNS setof json
AS $$
  DECLARE json_object json;
  DECLARE i json;
  
  BEGIN
    SELECT (arg_t)::json into json_object;
    
    FOR item IN SELECT * FROM json_array_elements((json_object->>'arg_t')::json)
    LOOP
       RAISE NOTICE ' % ', json_object->>'id';
    END LOOP;   
 END;
  $$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Function call:

```
select parse_json('{"id": 1,"name": "Amit","Class": "12th"}');
```

I want to loop ID. And run the function for as many as ID we pass as argument

Comment: What is the output you want?

Comment: Note that `DECLARE` starts a block where multiple variables can be declared. There is no need to start a new block for each variable.

Comment: Your sample data only contains a single ID. Do you plan to call that function with a JSON  array? e.g. `[{"id": 1, ...}, {"id": 2, ...}]`

Comment: Why does this function take TEXT as input, when it must be of type JSON?

Comment: `RETURNS setof json` is not accurate - what do you want the function to do? Also `json_object->>'arg_t'` doesn't make sense, nor casting that to JSON, nor using `json_array_elements` when you are not passing an array.

Comment: I want to call multiple ID's like [{"id": 1, ...}, {"id": 2, ...}]

Comment: I want a function which take argument as a text then it converts to json and then we loop it and print all id's using look